# extension=php_mssql.dll - error load

Tags: php, sql-server, iis-7

I am configuring a server IIS7 to work with php and mssql in php.ini and when I try to call the "extension = php_mssql.dll" appears to me an error when I refresh the site.

"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it can not be displayed. "

Thanks

Comment: Look into the server's error log to see what the problem is.

Comment: thanks Pekka, but i don't know where is Error log in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention your PHP version, but here's a relevant article that suggests two DLLs that may be missing:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1164387.aspx

But note that the key message of the article is that php_mssql.dll depends on an old MSSQL driver that's no longer supported, so moving to the new Microsoft PHP MSSQL driver seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The php_mssql.dll is missing the latest 5.3 releases because support for this extension has been dropped. Version 5.3.1 stills has a version which you can also use in 5.3.5. Just copy it to the ext dir.